# ng-list with regex

Tags: angularjs, angular-nglist

I found an old jsfiddle where someone is using a regex pattern for the delimiter with an `ng-list` http://jsfiddle.net/MrSteve/tnY6m/1/.

I tried this in Angular 1.3.x and can't get it to work.

Is there any way to accept multiple delimiters with `ng-list`, so I can split on a `,` or a `;`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this fiddle is your solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/MrSteve/tnY6m/1/

You should change your regex to: `/[,;]/`

Comment: the fiddle uses an old version of angular it no longer works with the current versions of angular

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, I t would seem that the angular no longer supports regex as delimiters. What I did was set up a $watch for that variable and within that watcher I made the split.

So I wanted to get a list of emails from a textarea. I set up a names and an emails variable in my scope. I had to split them by a comma or a new line

```
<textarea ng-model="names" rows="4"  width="100%"></textarea>
```

Then in my controller I set up the watcher

```
$scope.$watch('names', function() {
        var re = /[,\s]/g;
        $scope.emails = $scope.names.split(re)
    });
```